# How do I get machine-sized integer for FFI?

Tags: int, rust, ffi

In dealing with foreign code, I have to take pointers to a C struct of the form

```
typedef struct {
  int two;  
  int nd;
  char typekind; 
  ...           
} PyArrayInterface;
```

Obviously the size of `int` is unknown.  How do I represent this struct in rust?  It's probably `i32`, but I might run across an ILP64 data model some day...

At this point my only idea is to create an enum to wrap the struct, check the architecture at runtime, and do the right thing.  It's pretty goofy to have an `if` statement and a `transmute` each time I need to get the struct from C, but I've got nothing better at the moment...

Comment: Please don't edit your post too often in a meaning changing manner and for a second question open a new question-thread please. Let's keep SO questions atomic :)

Comment: My bad :).  I have to get more disciplined about waiting longer before I post... I erased my second question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle FFI types you should use the [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate. You can find it's documentation [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/).

The two types you need are `libc::c_int` and `libc::c_char`.

[This chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) from the Rust book gives a neat introduction and also mentions `c_int`.

Comment: 2: Or use `libc::c_char` to let the library decide.